# CSS: absolute DIV inside another absolute DIV

Tags: css, css-position

I have the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.container
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 300px;
        border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;

        position: absolute;
        top: 20px; /* Will change depending on where the box is opened */
        left: 20px; /* Same */

        overflow: hidden;
    }

    div.block
    { /* Will exceed 300px in height */
        width: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>

[...]

<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <!-- hyperlinks -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create something that imitates scrolling - a box that moves around within a box. IE does this beautifully; the 'block' `div` is perfectly hidden within the 'container' `div`. Every other browser throws the 'block' `div` at the top of the page, above the 'container' `div` and positioning relative to the page.

How do I get everyone else to behave like IE does?

Comment: Im getting the same result in both IE and FF - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/DQChN/. Unless im missing something?

Comment: Looks fine in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/Ahw5u/1/.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `div` should have a fixed width and height, with the CSS property `overflow: auto;`. Anything inside of this `div` that's larger than it will cause the parent div to display scrollbars.

You're then free to set it to `position` to `absolute`, and place it anywhere you like.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/duc44/